# Request object for validate_callback

Tags: plugin-json-api, rest-api, endpoints

I'm trying to define a new REST Api endpoint based on WP REST API (version 2) and have question relating to what arguments are available to the `validate_callback` and `sanitize_callback`.  Is the `Request` object made available for these callbacks?

For example:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        'args' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'validate_callback' => 'my_validation'
            ),
        ),
    ) );
} );

function my_validation (WP_REST_Request $request) {
   return is_numeric( $request['id'] );   // Is this acceptable???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search through the WP-API source revealed where `validate_callback` is being used:

**wp-api/lib/infrastructure/class-wp-rest-request.php**

```
$valid_check = call_user_func( $arg['validate_callback'], $param, $this, $key );
```

In this case, `$this` is an instance of `WP_Rest_Request` - so there's one. Now, for `sanitize_callback`:

```
$this->params[ $type ][ $key ] = call_user_func( $attributes['args'][ $key ]['sanitize_callback'], $value, $this, $key );
```

Same file, there's the `$this` you're looking for. So yes, both should get an instance of `WP_Rest_Request` as their second argument.